# Uninitialized constant for Rails 6 with Zeitwerk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, uninitialized-constant, zeitwerk

I'm upgrading my Rails app from v5 to v6.
The files are structured as:

```rb
lib
 |- container
   |- my_module_a
   |  |- my_class.rb
   |  |- class_two.rb
   |- my_module_b
```

**my_module** directory has no files in it, only `my_module_a` and `my_module_b` directories.

**class_one.rb** contents:

```
module MyModuleA
  class MyClass
    # definitions...
  end
end
```

config/application.rb has:

```
 config.eager_load_paths += %W[
    #{config.root}/lib/container
    #{config.root}/lib/container/my_module_a
 ]
```

`bin/rails zeitwerk:check` prints All is good!

However, when running the `rails server` and it reaches the call of the `MyClass` class

```
obj = Container::MyModule::MyClass.new(...)
```

it prints

```
uninitialized constant Container::MyModuleA
```

Comment: Remove the `MyApp::` part from your call, all the classes and modules that you define in your app are not nested in the app top level name. When you define a new `User` model, you're using it directly by calling `User` not `MyApp::User`.

Comment: @SébastienP. I updated the question's directory structure. It was confusing...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `Container::MyModuleA::MyClassA`, the class definition should be:

```rb
module Container
  module MyModuleA
    class MyClass
      # definitions...
    end
  end
end
```

Your current directory structure and the class definition are different `container/my_module_a/my_class` vs `MyModuleA::MyClass`, the best practice is to prefix your classes with a module name that matches the directory tree. In development rails is disabling eager loading meaning that code is loaded on the fly (to reduce booting time) and when you call `Container::MyModuleA::MyClassA`, it will lookup for the `container/my_module_a/my_class_a` file, check the content to find `Container::MyModuleA::MyClassA` which is not defined right now are the class definition is not nested in the `Container` module.

More information about autoloading vs eager loading here: https://www.bigbinary.com/books/learn-rubyonrails-book/loading-behavior-of-ruby-on-rails-in-depth

Comment: Please, note that this answer is not taking into account that `lib/container` is in the autoload paths, and therefore there is no `Container` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the description above has multiple typos:

- I don't see a `my_module` directory
- Since `lib/container/my_module_a` is in the autoload paths, the `my_class.rb` file in that directory is expected to define a top-level `MyClass` class, not `MyModuleA::MyClass` as shown above
- Yet, `zeitwerk:check` passes

Would be cool to have real names and real code to avoid assuming things. If not possible, at least double-check and update the problem statement.

The main thing to take into account is that autoload paths have to comply with the [documented project structure conventions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#project-structure). Anything pushed to the eager load paths is considered to be an autoload path too.

You should remove the configuration for `#{config.root}/lib/container/my_module_a` unless you know what you are doing and really need [nested root directories](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#nested-root-directories).

Then, if you leave `#{config.root}/lib/container` in the configuration, the code shown above is mostly good because this configuration says `lib/container` is a root directory containing top-level constants. But then, existing code should accordingly NOT use a `Container` constant nobody is defining.

So,

```rb
obj = Container::MyModule::MyClass.new(...)
```

does not square with what you have, should be

```rb
obj = MyModuleA::MyClass.new(...)
```

Please don't hesitate to follow up if more help is needed.